# What is the difference between an ArrayBuffer and a Blob?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reading http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ and trying to figure out the difference between an `ArrayBuffer` and a `Blob`.

Aren't both containers comprised of bits? Hence, couldn't both containers be viewed in many ways (as 32-bit chunks, 16-bit chunks, etc.)?

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` (and its _Views_ such as `DataView` and _Typed arrays_) for binary **data**, `Blob` for binary **files**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's explained on the page.

ArrayBuffer

> An ArrayBuffer is a generic fixed-length container for binary data. They are super handy if you need a generalized buffer of raw data, **but the real power behind these guys is that you can create "views" of the underlying data using JavaScript typed arrays**. In fact, multiple views can be created from a single ArrayBuffer source. For example, you could create an 8-bit integer array that shares the same ArrayBuffer as an existing 32-bit integer array from the same data. The underlying data remains the same, we just create different representations of it.

BLOB

> If you want to work directly with a Blob and/or don't need to manipulate any of the file's bytes, use xhr.responseType='blob':

Comment: Hmm, but couldn't you view both in different ways as well since they are both containers of bits essentially?

Comment: Sure .. but I'm guessing an ArrayBuffer has readily available functions for it? a BLOB can be anything, an ArrayBuffer is well defined structure.

Comment: Ah, ok, so an ArrayBuffer just exposes an interface for doing that.

Comment: Still not clear, to be honest. What do you mean by can "a BLOB can be anything?". Ain't it just a sequence of bytes, just like ArrayBuffer?

Comment: An ArrayBuffer is in the memory, available for manipulation. A Blob can be on disk, in cache memory, and other places not readily available. But the data from a Blob can be copied into an ArrayBuffer.

Comment: I can't find any information on performance implications of converting between these. If you have a Blob that is known to be in memory, does converting to an ArrayBuffer (using `Response()` or the new `Blob.arrayBuffer()` or other means) copy the data, or return a reference to it? And similarly the other direction: if you have an ArrayBuffer and want a Blob of it, does that copy the data or not?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom, citation needed.

Comment: explanation of "Blob": if you want to work directly with a Blob, then ...  this is called a recursive explanation

Answer (score 133):

**Summary**

Unless you **need the ability to write/edit** (using an `ArrayBuffer`), then **`Blob` format is probably best**.

**Detail**

I came to this question from a [*different* html5rocks page.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), and I found [@Bart van Heukelom's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821096/what-is-the-difference-between-an-arraybuffer-and-a-blob#comment41489269_11821109) to be helpful, so I wanted to elevate them to an answer here.

I also found helpful resources specific to `ArrayBuffer` and `Blob` objects. In summary: **despite the emphasis on `Blob` being immutable/"raw data" `Blob` objects are *easy to work with***.

Resources that compare / contrast `ArrayBuffer` vs `Blob`:

- Mutability

  - an `ArrayBuffer` can be **changed** (e.g. with a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView))
  - a `Blob` is **immutable**
- Source / Availability in Memory

  - Quoting [Bart van Heukelom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821096/what-is-the-difference-between-an-arraybuffer-and-a-blob#comment41489269_11821109):

  > - An ArrayBuffer is in the memory, **available** for manipulation.
  > - A Blob can be on disk, in cache memory, and other places **not readily available**
- Access Layer

  - `ArrayBuffer` will require **some access layer** like [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)
  - `Blob` can be passed directly into other functions like [`window.URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), as seen in the example from [OP's URL](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).

    - However, as [Mörre points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821096/what-is-the-difference-between-an-arraybuffer-and-a-blob/39951543?noredirect=1#comment77413345_39951543) you may still need [`File`-related interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and API's like `FileReader` to work with a Blob.
- Convert / Generate

  - You can generate `Blob` from `ArrayBuffer` and vice versa, which addresses the OP's *"Aren't both containers comprised of bits?"*
  - **ArrayBuffer can be generated from a Blob**   [using the `FileReader`'s `readAsArrayBuffer` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsArrayBuffer()) , or the [async method  `const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) (thanks to @Darren G)
  - **Blob can be generated from an ArrayBuffer** [as @user3405291 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821096/what-is-the-difference-between-an-arraybuffer-and-a-blob/39951543?noredirect=1#comment86677751_39951543) `new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)]);`, shown in
    [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44148694/3405291)
- Use in Other Libraries

  - [`jsZip`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html); `(new JSZip()).loadAsync(...)` accepts *both* `ArrayBuffer` and `Blob`: `String/Array of bytes/ArrayBuffer/Uint8Array/Buffer/Blob/Promise`
- How does protocol handle ArrayBuffer vs Blob

  - Websocket (aka WS / WSS)

    - Use the [webSocket's `binaryType` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/binaryType) (could have values "arraybuffer" or "blob") to "control the type of binary data being received over the WebSocket connection."
  - XmlHttpRequest (aka XHR)

    - Use the [xhr's `responseType` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)  to "to change the expected response type from the server" (valid values include "arraybuffer", "blob", and others like "document", "json", and "text")
    - > the response property will contain the entity body **according to `responseType`**, as an ArrayBuffer, Blob, Document, JSON, or string.

Other helpful documentation:

- [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)

> The `ArrayBuffer` object is used to represent a generic, fixed-length
> raw binary data buffer. You **cannot directly manipulate** the contents of
> an `ArrayBuffer`; instead, you create one of the **typed array objects or
> a `DataView` object** which represents the buffer in a specific format,
> and **use that to read and write** the contents of the buffer.

- [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

> A `Blob` object represents a file-like object of **immutable**, raw data.
> `Blob` represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native
> format. The **`File` interface** is based on `Blob`, inheriting blob
> functionality and expanding it to support files on the user's system.

Comment: As I just found out when I got a binary response from a websocket you get a Blob there - and the disadvantage of the Blob seems to be that **you cannot even read it**. It's just a handle. I needed to get a few bytes from that blob. You need to create a `FileReader`, see ["Example for extracting data from a Blob" here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) - which adds yet another asynchronous function before you can access anything from your Blob.

Comment: Thanks, @Mörre , I incorporated your comment. I guess that's consistent with the documentation: `A Blob object represents a file-like object`, but I explicitly added that Blobs may need some kind of "access layer" (before the edit, I implied Blobs didn't need any "access layer")

Comment: `arrayBuffer` can be converted to `Blob` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44148694/3405291 "ArrayBuffer to blob conversion
") like this: `new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)]);` I tested it, and it works for PNG images.

Comment: @Mörre You can slice a blob to return a new blob containing just the bytes you want and then read that. If you want real performance then workers support synchronous file reading and you can transfer ownership of (instead of cloning) ArrayBuffers between workers and window processes almost instantly

Comment: A Blob can also be converted to ArrayBuffer with the async method blob.arraybuffer() e.g. `const buffer = await blobFile.arrayBuffer()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer

Comment: "Blob can become" no, as you said before, it's immutable, so it cannot become anything. You can generate an ArrayBuffer from a Blob, or a Blob from an ArrayBuffer, but in both case, you duplicate the data, nothing becomes something else.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, I will change the language to "generate an ArrayBuffer from a Blob"

Comment: @Mörre FWIW when creating the websocket you can specify if you want it to output binary data as Blobs or as ArrayBuffers, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/binaryType)

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with something that is more similar to an immutable file that may be retrieved, stored, or served as a file over HTTP, a Blob has a useful feature: `blob.type` ([Web API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/type), [Nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)). This returns a MIME type (such as `image/png`) that you can you use for your Content-Type HTTP header when serving the blob.