# ArrayBuffer to blob conversion

Tags: javascript, djvu

I have a project where I need to display djvu schemas in browser.

I found this old [library on Github](https://github.com/lebedkin/minidjvu.js) which, as far as I understood, converts djvu files to bmp and then puts them into canvas element.

As I said, library is old(last commit was 5 years ago), so I need to make some corrections. Main problem is that lib uses obsolete BlobBuilder.

Steps I made to solve this problem:

1. Decompress this library via Chrome DevTools
2. Initial error is at line 3774 `var c = "undefined" != typeof MozBlobBuilder ? MozBlobBuilder : "undefined" != typeof WebKitBlobBuilder ? WebKitBlobBuilder : console.log("warning: cannot build blobs")`
3. I commented out this line
4. Next, I commented out line `c = new c;` and some of following lines too.

So, now it looks this way(variable I is array buffer, and ololo1 and ololo2 are some kind of offset and limit)

```
var c = new Blob(new Uint8Array(new Uint8Array(I,ololo1,ololo2)))
              , b = b.createObjectURL(c)
              , c = document.getElementById(kb)
              , f = c.getContext("2d")
              , h = new Image
              , g = a[Ea >> 2]
              , i = a[Fa >> 2]
              , j = c.width
              , k = Math.round(i * j / g);

            h.onload = function()
            {
                var a = g / j;
                4 < a && (a = 4);
                1 > a && (a = 1);
                f.globalAlpha = 1;

                for (N = 0; N < a; N++)
                    f.drawImage(h, N, N, g - a + N, i - a + N, 0, 0, j, k),
                    f.globalAlpha *= 1 - 1 / a;
                R(h.complete, "Image /bmp.bmp could not be decoded")
            }
            ;
            h.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
                console.log(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj);
                console.log("Image /bmp.bmp could not be decoded!")
            }           
            ;
```

And now I stuck at error "Image /bmp.bmp could not be decoded!"(throwed in h.onerror handler).

So, my question is: what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The original was `c.append((new Uint8Array(new Uint8Array(I,ololo1,ololo2))).buffer)`.
I don't see why the author nested his Uint8array inside an new one...  
You should be fine with just new `Blob([new Uint8Array(I,ololo1,ololo2)])`;

Comment: @Kaiido many thanks, works like a charm. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I don't know why the author did wrap his `Uint8Array` in a new one... note that I don't really know either the deprecated `BlobBuilder` API, but one typo I can see in your code is that you need to wrap your *TypedArray* in a normal `Array`:

```js
new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer, byteOffset, length)]);
```

The `Blob()` constructor takes a [blobParts sequence](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-blobParts) as first parameter, and then searches for *BufferSource*, *USVStrings* and *`Blob`* elements in this sequence. So when you pass a *TypedArray*, it will actually iterate over all the entries of this *TypedArray* and treat these as *USVString* (and thus convert their numerical value to UTF-8 strings in the *`Blob`*). That's rarely what you want, so better always pass an *`Array`* in this constructor.

Note that if you don't need to slice the buffer, it's probably better to directly pass it instead of using an intermediary `Uint8Array` (but still in a normal `Array`):

```js
new Blob([buffer]);
```

Comment: Saved my day as well (I passed in an arrayBuffer to work with binary data, but needed that wrapped as Array). However, I think Uint8Array should be passed in without the brackets as it's already an array, and therefore wasn't the OP's problem. You need the brackets around an ArrayBuffer.

Comment: @aamarks No, if you pass an Uint8Array, you will save all its 0~255 values as utf8 strings since the Blob constructor won't access it `.buffer` property and that it's probably what is wanted to save the contained data as binary.

Comment: I see, thanks. It seems passing in the buffer the Uint8Array view is based on, or the Uint8Array, both work as long as either is in brackets.

Comment: Uint8Array is a waste. You do not need it. Just `new Blob([buffer])`. ArrayBuffer is a byte array.

Comment: ^ it's only a view. Not certain if the starting point was the ArrayBuffer or another typed view? This could derail the blob builder in new Blob(...)

Comment: @Dominik is right that normally you don't need to wrap a buffer inside a TypedArray, but here OP's code was actually slicing the ArrayBuffer, hence their need to use that Uint8Array constructor here.

Comment: Is it normal that typescript complains with this syntax: `Type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to type 'string | Blob'`

Comment: @Sharcoux could you show your TS?

Comment: Actually, it's because there is a conflict between @types/react-native Blob and @types/web Blob definitions... I don't know how to solve this kind of thing, though. But I'll open an issue maybe

Answer (score 60):

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(32);

new Blob([buffer]);
```

so the Uint8Array should be

```
new Blob([new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4]).buffer]);
```