# Return a File object from a local filepath in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, buffer, fs-extra

I am trying to write a function that returns me a `Blob` or `File` object, `blob_object`, while taking in the local filepath of an object, `tmpFilePath`, and I have to use NodeJS to do it as the function is used as part of a Firebase cloud function. I have tried many methods, but none of them work. They mainly revolve around this.

Attempt 1: Using `streamToBlob`. Inspired from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/9ko5au/how_do_i_convert_a_buffer_like_buffer_89_50_4e_47/)

```
const streamToBlob = require('stream-to-blob');
const fs = require('fs-extra');


const input_read_stream = fs.createReadStream(tmpFilePath);
const blob_object = await streamToBlob(input_read_stream);
```

Error: `ReferenceError: Blob is not defined`

Attempt 2: using `blob`. Inspired from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147912/arraybuffer-to-blob-conversion/44148694)

```
const Blob = require('blob');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const file_buffer = fs.readFileSync(tmpFilePath);
const blob_object = new Blob([file_buffer]);
```

Error:  `TypeError: Blob is not a constructor`.

A workable solution would mean that upon writing code in my file, `file.js`, I would be able to run `node file.js` and console.log a `Blob` or `File` object. Does anyone know how this can be done in a series of steps? I'm on Node 8.

Comment: This will help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%C2%B4t-create-blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%C2%B4t-create-blobs)

Comment: @KaiLehmann I also saw that post earlier too, but did not understand how the solutions given will solve my problem. They are either working with client side code or doing it via requests.

Comment: const Blob = require("cross-blob"); Doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Did you get a solution

Comment: @SayanDey I still faced this problem when trying out the solution. However, I realised my client has a slightly different requirement so this situation could be avoided creating files from the node side

Answer (score 5):

As of writing, `Blob` support is still experimental, but this should work in recent versions of Node.js:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import { Blob } from "buffer";

let buffer = fs.readFileSync("./your_file_name");
let blob = new Blob([buffer]);
```

So your second example should work if you upgrade Node to v16.

Comment: This saved me. I lost 4 days trying to have a PersistenFile instance (from formidable package) appended to a FormData and sending it as a fetch api request. Buffer + Blob solved it.