# NodeJs fetch with file to Golang API

Tags: node.js, ajax, go, fetch

I try to post via node-fetch to golang API files with some structure, I can make it from postman, but no way from NodeJS

Hi there. im at dead end, i had tried everything...

I need make a request to golang api, i can create it in Postman: its look like this:
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIpGv.png)

And I need to repeat it in NodeJs, But i always getted bad request from API

here is my code on Node

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('postUUID', postUuid)
json.data.uploadIds.map((upl, index) => {
    let file = data.files.find(el => el == upl.filename)
    formData.append(upl.uuid, fs.readFileSync(file));
})
let headers = new Headers()
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token)
headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
fetch(API+'/posts/uploadMediaFiles', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: formData
})
```

Difference with postman generated code only in `formdata.append("f2b07a43-f79f-4033-ab2d-bb3176934679", fileInput.files[0], "/file_0.jpg");` and i do instead of `formData.append(upl.uuid, fs.readFileSync(file));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) returns either a `string` or a `Buffer` containing only the contents of the file itself. This means you're passing only the raw contents of the file to `FormData.append()`, which in turn means your call to `fetch` will treat the resulting key/value pair *not* as a file - this only happens when passing a `value` with a `Blob` or `File` type ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#filename)).

Instead, cast the contents of the read file as an `Array` to a new `Blob` object, then pass both the blob object and the name of the file you want to the `FormData` field (a quick tip of the cap to the answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608132/return-a-file-object-from-a-local-filepath-in-nodejs)):

```js
formData.append(upl.uuid, new Blob([fs.readFileSync(file)]), upl.filename);
```

Comment: in this case i get
*source.on('error', function() {});
         ^
TypeError: source.on is not a function*

i tried to make *JSON.stringify(new Blob([fs.readFileSync(file)]))*, but no way

Comment: holy .... i fix it... instead of use npm *require('form-data')*, i update nodeJS and FormData is available without dependices, and it works great, so much thanks