# How to convert file into a blob or javascript file in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, multer

I have a function which receives a file in [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#api) format through multer package.. Now I want to upload this file to firebase storage, for that I need it in a `Blob` or in `javascript file` format.

My function is-

```js
const getFileURL = file => {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    let url = "";
    let err = null;
    const metadata = {
        contentType: file.mimetype,
    };
    const uploadFile = storageRef.child(name).put(file);
    uploadFile.on(
        "state_changed",
        function (snapshot) {},
        function (error) {
            console.log("errrroror", error);
            return error;
        },
        function () {
            uploadFile.snapshot.ref
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then(function (downloadURL) {
                    url = downloadURL;
                    return url;
                });
        }
    );
};
```

File received in the above function:

```json
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'file_name.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './public/images',
  filename: '85d68e32b2b18adbfc7d0f72b5746e43',
  path: 'public/images/85d68e32b2b18adbfc7d0f72b5746e43',
  size: 96966
}
```

Caller Function:

```js
uploadImage = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const url = getFileURL(req.files[0]);
        return res.json({ location: url });
    } catch (e) {
        return res.json(e);
    }
}
```

I'm getting error as :`Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in 'put' at index 0: Expected Blob or File.`

Comment: can you show the caller function?

Comment: @ShivamSingla updated

Comment: Are you using `mutler.single` or `mutler.array` or `mutler.fields` ?

Comment: @ShivamSingla I'm using mutter.any(). `getFileURL` is receiving file properly, I don't think problem is in the calling function

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```js
// ...snip
const blob = new Blob([file.buffer])
const uploadFile = storageRef.child(name).put(blob)
// ...snip
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57139182/11642727) answer

Comment: Hi, actually 'Blob' function is not defined in Nodejs. So I'm getting error as `ReferenceError: Blob is not defined`

Comment: @YashBoura Try [blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob) for client side or [node-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-blob) for server side

Comment: I want to handle in server side. No luck with node-blob too.

Comment: @YashBoura are the firebase storage API available for server-side too? As far as I know, we have to use google client libraries to upload to firebase storage. [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#top_of_page)

Comment: Well you are right,  I have to use google cloud for this. Thanks