# Convert buffer to blob and set it to FormData in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, blob, buffer, multer, form-data

Assume I have two servers both run on NodeJS. First receive a file using Multer and convert it to buffer as output, then convert it to blob and put it to form-data and post it via NodeJS https.request to second server. What I cannot handle is how to convert buffer to blob in NodeJS. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does it help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147912/arraybuffer-to-blob-conversion/44148694

Comment: I tried it but I receive this error: TypeError: Blob is not a constructor

Comment: Yes, node doesn't have Blob. check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637644/how-do-i-create-a-blob-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

If you use [formdata-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-node#comparison), it's got it's own Blob class.