# web worker - data undefined when passed back to main thread

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-worker

I'm trying to use a web worker to get some data and then pass them back to the main thread. I have tried with this code but it will not work as expected

```
onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  if( e.data[0] === 'fetchData' ){
    fetch('https://example.com/platform/api/v1/endpoint')
    .then( (res) => res.json() )
    .then( async (data) => {
      const imagesData = await Promise.all(
        data.map( async (item) => {
          let res = await fetch(item.src);
          let img = await res.blob();
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(img);
          reader.onloadend = () => { 
            return { 
              title: item.title, 
              link: item.link, 
              src: reader.result 
            }
          }
        })
      )
      postMessage(imagesData);
    })
  }
}
```

The imagesData after a `console.log` will contain an array of seven undefined elements, how I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

I've changed the code in vue front-end and into the worker and now I'm able to get the data but sometimes the worker will not work and I will not able to get the data or I get just two entries but the expected number is seven items for the front-end. Here is how I've modified the code, maybe I need to terminate the work before use another one?
NB: I'm creating a tab override chrome extension

vue front-end code

```
<script>
const worker = new Worker('services.js');

export default {
  name: 'App',
  beforeCreate() {
    worker.postMessage(['fetchData']);
  },
  created() {
    this.init();
    this.clock();
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mostVisited: [],
      imagesData: [],
      isLoading: true 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      worker.onmessage = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        this.imagesData = e.data; 
        this.isLoading = false; 
      }
      browser.topSites.get().then( (sites) => this.mostVisited = sites ); 
    } //end init
  }
</script>
```

web worker code

```
onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  if( e.data[0] === 'fetchData' ){
    fetch('https://example.com/platform/api/v1/endpoint')
    .then( (res) => res.json() )
    .then( async (data) => {
      let imagesData = [];
      await Promise.all(
        data.map( async (item) => {
          let res = await fetch(item.src);
          let img = await res.blob();
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(img);
          reader.onloadend = () => { 
            imagesData.push({ title: item.title, link: item.link, src: reader.result });
          }
        })
      )
      postMessage(imagesData);
    }); // end then(data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for the asynchronous FileReader to have read your files before resolving the outer Promise, so the `Promise.all` Promise resolves after `let img = await res.blob();` but before `onloadend` does.

Since you are in a Worker context, you can use the *synchronous* [FileReaderSync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync) API, which would give something like

```
.then( async (data) => {
  let imagesData = [];
  await Promise.all(
    data.map( async (item) => {
      let res = await fetch(item.src);
      let img = await res.blob();
      let reader = new FileReaderSync();
      const result = reader.readAsDataURL(img);
      imagesData.push({ title: item.title, link: item.link, src: result });
    })
  )
  postMessage(imagesData);
});
```

But I'm 99% confident that you don't even need that data: URL, and that it will do more harm than anything.

Remember that the data: URL from a FileReader always encode to base64, which will produce a DOMString containing 134% of the original data, that you multiply per 2 since DOMStrings are stored in UTF-16.
Then, to pass that data to the main context, the browser will have to serialize the data using the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), and for DOMStrings that means a simple copy in memory. Each image now takes in memory about 5 times its real size, and it's even before the main context starts parsing it again to binary data so it can build the pixels data...

Instead, simply pass the Blob you get as `img`.
[Blobs' inner data is passed by reference by the structured clone algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641798/is-copying-a-large-blob-over-to-a-worker-expensive/63642296#63642296), so all you copy is the small js wrapper around.
Then when you need to display these images on the main context, use [`URL.createObejctURL(img)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) which will return a blob: URL directly pointing to that same Blob's data, which is still stored only once in memory.

```
.then( async (data) => {
  let imagesData = [];
  await Promise.all(
    data.map( async (item) => {
      let res = await fetch(item.src);
      let img = await res.blob();
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(img);
      imagesData.push({ title: item.title, link: item.link, src: url, file: img });
    })
  )
  postMessage(imagesData);
});
```

Comment: I didn't know that I was occupy a lot of memory by using the file reader, I was thinking that it was the correct way to hide the original direct link to the resource but I was wrong. Thanks for the explaination, I will modify the code to apply the fix as you suggested. Just a littke thing, I need to pass also the blob into the array? I see that you've linked it into the file key of the object pushed into the array

Comment: No you don't, it's jist I wasn't sire what you were doing with that data URL. For instance if at some point you need to upload it back, tjen do it directly with the Blob, once again it costs nothing passing it by postMessage.