# Can not clone object to web worker

Tags: javascript, fonts, web-worker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick='UseLocalFontsButton()'>Click Me!</button>
  <script>

    async function UseLocalFontsButton() {
      try {
        const array = await self.queryLocalFonts();

        for (const font of array) {
          // blob() returns a Blob containing the bytes of the font.
          const bytes = await font.blob();
          console.log(`bytes.size = ${bytes.size}`);
          console.log(`bytes.type = ${bytes.type}`);
          // process font
        };
      } 
      catch (e) {
        console.warn(`Error: ${e.message}`);
      }
    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I am getting local fonts and processing it. It works but I need to move font processing part to worker thread. I cant move everything because `queryLocalFonts` only works on main thread.

Here is my try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick='UseLocalFontsButton()'>Click Me!</button>

  <script>

    async function UseLocalFontsButton() {
      try {
        const array = await self.queryLocalFonts();

        let worker = new Worker('worker.js');
        worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify(array));
      } 
      catch (e) {
        console.warn(`Error: ${e.message}`);
      }
    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the worker:

```
(function () {
    onmessage = async function handleMessageFromMain(msg) 
    {
        var array = JSON.parse(msg.data);

        console.log('array = ', array);

        try {
            for (const font of array) {
                // blob() returns a Blob containing the bytes of the font.
                const bytes = await font.blob();
                console.log(`bytes.size = ${bytes.size}`);
                console.log(`bytes.type = ${bytes.type}`);
                // process font
            };
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(`Error: ${e.message}`);
        }
    };
})();
```

I am getting error: `Error: font.blob is not a function`. Looks like font object is not properly copied to worker thread. Can you hint how that can be done?

Comment: Why would you stringify at all? (when you postMessage)

Comment: Without stringify I got `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': FontData object could not be cloned.`

Comment: Blobs can't be passed to workers. You can try to convert it to `ArrayBuffer` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I was trying to do that on worker thread as well, but looks like it is not possible, I will convert it to `ArrayBuffer` and then pass..

Comment: @KonradLinkowski you can very well pass Blobs to Workers and you should in most cases since there is no copy involved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641798/is-copying-a-large-blob-over-to-a-worker-expensive/63642296#63642296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to serialize your data to JSON when you post it to a Worker (or other `MessagePort` objects for that matter); the `postMessage()` method has its own [cloning algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) able to pass [many different JS object types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types) that JSON doesn't support.

And while `FontData` is not part of these many object types, `Blob` is. So what you need to do is to extract all the your `FontData` instances as `Blob` and send these `Blob` objects to your worker.

That would give:

```js
// main script
async function UseLocalFontsButton() {
  try {
    const fonts = await self.queryLocalFonts();
    const toTransfer = [];
    for(const font of fonts) {
      toTransfer.push({
        // You're free to add whatever other info you need
        name: font.postscriptName,
        blob: await font.blob()
      });
    }
    const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
    worker.postMessage(toTransfer);
    worker.onmessage = ({data}) => {
      log(data);
    }
  } 
  catch (e) {
    log(`Error: ${e.message}`);
  }
};
```

```js
// worker script
onmessage = async ({data}) => {
  postMessage(`Received ${data.length} Blobs`);
  for(const {blob, name} of data) {
    const buf = await blob..arrayBuffer();
    // Do your analysis on the font's data
  }
};
```

[**Live example**](https://worker-querylocalfonts.glitch.me/) as a Glitch project since StackSnippet's don't allow access to local fonts. ([editor](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/worker-querylocalfonts?path=script.js)).